# Is it possible to use long double as an integer? (adding, substracting, multiplying, dividing, perbit operations ...)

Tags: c++

As far as I know in C++ standart `sizeof(long double)` is 10 byte = 80 bit => the variable of this `long double` type can carry 2^80 different values. So my question is here, is it possible to write some wrapper or I don't know what (using, maybe, perbit operations). To use `long double` (or it wrapper) as full integer? And if there is possible, then why standart doesn't give as 80bit integer?

Comment: You are thinking of the floating point registers on the processor (which are 80 bits). The sizeof(long double) may not be the same size.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard does not specify the exact size of `long double`.  All it says is that

> the type long double provides at least
>   as much precision as double.

On my computer, a `long double` is actually 16 bytes (128-bit) in size.

That said, you can create an arbitrarily large integer type using arrays, however usually you will need a special library for this because arithmetic operations on such arrays are non-trivial to implement efficiently.  If you need to work with larger integers, look into an [arbitrary precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library, such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You may better wrap array of char than double. This would give the flexibility of any integer size.

If you are looking for arbitrary precision numbers you may look at [MAPM](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~ringx004/mapm-main.html).

> Why standart doesn't give as 80bit integer?

Standard does not say anything about integer sizes. Integer may be 80 bit if the compiler creator wants it to be so.